# Maximum Number of Vertices in an m-ary Tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

I'm trying to find a formula for the maximum number of vertices (both internal nodes and leaves) in an m-ary tree with height h.

I think that this is equal to $1+m+m^2+m^3+...+m^h$ because it's m-ary, and then you use the formula for a sum of a geometric series to get $$ \frac{m^{h+1}-1}{m-1}$$

I just wanted to check my work, is this right?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It seems correct